# Is it possible to show the iPad screen in a browser window of MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, ipad

I want to mirror my iPad screen to MacBook. But I want to show the screen in a browser windows in the MacBook so that I can show one browser window where I am doing some work and then switch to another browser window instantly to show my iPad screen where I am drawing some stuff in the iPad. I want these drawings to be synced to Macbook.